# My code works with Paste but not Paste Special Transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that copies a column of data from multiple closed workbooks and pastes it into a single master workbook.

The code works well so far, but it pastes the data into a single column -it pastes the data from closed workbook 1, then finds the next empty row and pastes the data from closed workbook 2 below it and so on. I need it to 'transpose' the data when it pastes, so the data goes across the row.

I've successfully got the Paste Special Transpose code to work on its own in another workbook but when I try to insert it into my code, to replace the existing Paste lines, I get Runtime error 1004 'PasteSpecial method of Range class failed'

Can someone help?

Here's my code, with the Paste Special part with ' in front

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

 Dim MyFile As String

 Dim erow

 Dim Filepath As String

 Filepath = "Z:\Functional workstreams\Risk and compliance\Compliance steering group\Life & Limb\RETURNS - 2017\Test\"

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
 Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
 Range("D3:D24").Copy

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 ActiveWorkbook.Close

 erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

 'ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select

 'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 25))

MyFile = Dir
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the workbook, and by doing so you lose the ability to paste special.

Try assigning the workbook to a variable, and then use the variable to close the workbook after you have pasted the range.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim Filepath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, src_wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Filepath = "Z:\Functional workstreams\Risk and compliance\Compliance steering group\Life & Limb\RETURNS - 2017\Test\"

    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        Set src_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)
        Range("D3:D24").Copy

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        ws.Range("A" & erow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        src_wb.Close False

        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```